# Download Multiparted File from Springboot controller using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot

So I am trying to fetch multiparted file from sql database fetch from the Springboot controller. I used this ajax request:

Here is my Controller api

```
@PostMapping("/fetch-file-data")
public ResponseEntity<?> getFile(@RequestBody Long id){

    FileData file = fileService.getFile(id);

    System.out.println("file name is: " + file .getFileName());
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(file .getFileType()))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file .getFileName() + "\"")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(file .getData()));
}
```

My object contains the following with corresponding getters and setters:

```
    private String fileName;
    private String fileType;
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;
```

The Ajax Request:

```js
                 $.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     contentType : "application/json",
     url :"/api/fetch-file-data",
     data: JSON.stringify(id),
     /* dataType : "application/pdf", */
     cache : false,
     timeout : 600000,
     success : function(data) {
      alert("IM HERE SUCCESS");
      console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
      
      var pdfData =new Blob([data.data]);
         var link=document.createElement('a');
         link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfData);
         link.download=data.fileName;
         link.click();
     },
     error : function(e) { 
      alert("IM HERE FAIL FETCHING");
      console.log("ERROR : ", e);
     }
  
    });
```

The browser downloads the file but it does not load. I tried using datatype: "application/pdf" but the console logs say that there was a parsing error so i commented it out.

Comment: why the url is "/api/fetch-file-data-test" not url :"/api/fetch-file-data" like @PostMapping("/fetch-file-data") ?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I edited my question. I was testing another way in another api with -test.